# Software that allows concurrent backup and restore operation at the same time (if possible)

Tags: backup, hard-disk

Suppose there are three different folder (e.g. one network folder, local folder and one folder from a thumb-drive) that I need to backup and 4 restore operation (e.g. two operation to restore to local folder, one for a network folder and the last one for another portable hard-disk) that I need to execute.

Are there such software that at least allow one to concurrent backup the three different folder at the same time OR execute restore operation at the same time?

It will be great if it can do all the backup and restore operation all at the same time, or at the very least, queue each operation and allow user to continue add new operation.

Some requirements:

- Run on Windows Operating system (preferable) or if possible cross-platform solution
- Allows backup to be protected with some kind of encryption.
- Allow one to configure the type of backup method (such as full backup, incremental backup, etc)
- Allow one to schedule the backup and restore.
- Allow backup or restore from and to network storage folder, local folder (local hard disk), external storage devices such as thumb drive or portable hard disk)

Thank you.

Comment: With Linux/Unix, that sounds like a job for [RSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). There are specific backup solutions built on top of this. Should work on Mac as well. // Hint: Your question lacks a few requirements, such as a) do you need multiple backup generations (or just a single copy being updated each run), b) what storages must be supported, c) what OS the desired solution must run on.

Answer (score 1):

Any command-line copy program will do this. If you use `robocopy` (built into Windows XP and up) or `xcopy` with the `/D` option, both are capable of doing this. The backup and restore folders should probably not be the same as each other (that could be bad). If any of the drives are spinning drives and are the same, the performance will not be great, but it will work. You can start multiple command-line operations using the `start` command in Windows. You can create a batch file to perform these operations (or any combination thereof) on demand, or use Task Scheduler to schedule them to run on a schedule.